# How to avoid pressing enter twice when using getchar() to clear input buffer?

Tags: c, arrays, buffer-overflow, getchar

I have this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define SIZE 19

int main(){

char string[SIZE];

while (string[0] != 'A'){
 printf("\nEnter a new string.\n");
 fgets(string,SIZE,stdin);

 int storage = 0;
 while (storage != '\n') 
 {
   storage = getchar(); 
 }
 }
 }
```

The nested while loop with getchar() exists in case the inputted string exceeds the maximum number of characters string[] can hold. If that is not there, inputting a string with, say, 20 characters, would cause the output to be:

```
Enter a new string.
12345123451234512345

Enter a new string.

Enter a new string.
```

The problem is that this requires me to press enter twice in order to enter a new string: once for 'fgets' and one for the nested while loop (this is my understanding of what's going on).

Is there a way to change this so I only have to press 'Enter' once, or possibly a way to change the entire while loop into something more elegant?

Comment: `storage` is 0, and this code is testing it for equality to `'\n'`. It will probably be removed by the optimizer, and is probably not what you intended.

Comment: Sorry, ignore my comment; it's testing if it's _not_ equal to `'\n'`. This leads to the behaviour you are describing with the double-enter.

Answer (score 1):

If the buffer that receives from `fgets` contains a newline, you know it read everything that was inputted so you don’t need to do anything else.  If not, then you use the extra loop to flush the buffer.

Comment: That's not quite true.   `fgets()` will include the newline IF the buffer is long enough to reach and contain it, and also contain a nul terminator.   The OP is entering 20 characters, plus a newline, into a 19 character buffer, so a single call of `fgets()` will not contain the newline.

Comment: @Peter that’s basically what I said.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking correctly, you just need to think through how and when you need to empty the input buffer a bit further.

All *line-oriented* input functions (`fgets` and POSIX `getline`) will read, and include, the trailing `'\n'` in the buffers they fill (`fgets` only when sufficient space is provided in the buffer).

When using `fgets`, you have only two possible returns, (1) a pointer to the buffer filled, or (2) "`NULL` *on error or when end of file occurs while no characters have been read.*"

In case `fgets` returns a valid pointer, then it is up to you to determine whether a complete line of input was read, or whether the input exceeds the buffer size, leaving characters in the input buffer unread.

To make that determination, you check whether the last character in the buffer is `'\n'` **and if not**, whether the buffer contains `SIZE-1` characters indicating that characters remain in the input buffer. You can do that a number of ways, you can use `strchr` (to get a pointer to the `'\n'`), `strcspn` (to get an index to it) or good old `strlen` (to get the length of the string) and then check the character at `len-1`.

(a note on preference, you can use whatever method you like, but in either case of `strcspn` or `strlen`, save the index or length so it can be used to validate whether the input exceeded the buffer size or whether the user ended input by generating a manual `EOF`. You save the index or length to prevent having to make duplicate function calls to either)

It is also helpful to create a simple *helper-function* to clear the input buffer to avoid placing loops everywhere you need the check. A simple function will do the trick, e.g.

```
/* simple function to empty stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

of if you prefer the more-compact, but arguably less readable version, a single `for` loop will do, e.g.

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    for (int c = getchar(); c != '\n' && c != EOF; c = getchar()) {}
}
```

The remainder of your example can be structured to complete each of the tests described above to provide input handling as you have described (although using the 1st character of the buffer being `'A'` to control the loop is a bit strange), e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STRSIZE 19

/* simple function to empty stdin */
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}

int main (void) {

    char string[STRSIZE] = "";          /* initialize string all 0 */

    while (*string != 'A') {            /* up to you, but 'A' is a bit odd */
        size_t len = 0;                 /* variable for strlen return */
        printf ("enter a string: ");    /* prompt */
        if (!fgets (string, STRSIZE, stdin)) {  /* validate read */
            putchar ('\n');             /* tidy up with POSIX EOF on NULL */
            break;
        }
        len = strlen (string);              /* get length of string */
        if (len && string[len-1] == '\n')   /* test if last char is '\n' */
            string[--len] = 0;              /* overwrite with nul-character */
        else if (len == STRSIZE - 1)        /* test input too long */
            empty_stdin();                  /* empty input buffer */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

An arguably more useful approach is to have the loop exit if nothing is input (e.g. when <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone is pressed on an empty line). The test would then be `while (*string != '\n')`. A better approach rather is simply controlling your input loop with `while (fgets (string, STRSIZE, stdin))`. There, you have validated the read before entering the loop. You can also wrap the whole thing in a `for (;;)` loop and control the loop exit based on any input condition you choose.

Those are all possibilities to consider. Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets()` does read the newline IF (and only if) the buffer is long enough to reach and contain it, along with a trailing nul terminator.

Your sample input is 20 characters, which will be followed by a newline, and then a nul terminator.    That won't go into a buffer of 19 characters.

The simple way is to use `fgets()` in a loop, until the newline is included in the buffer.

```
printf("\nEnter a new string.\n");
do
{
     fgets(string,SIZE,stdin);
       /* 
            handle the input, noting it may or may not include a trailing '\n'
            before the terminating nul
       */
} while (strlen(string) > 0 && string[strlen(string) - 1] != '\n');
```

This loop will clear input up to and including the first newline, and also allow you to explicit handle (discard if needed) ALL the input received.   It is therefore not necessary to use a second loop with `getchar()`.

You haven't checked if `fgets()` returns `NULL`, so neither have I.  It is advisable to check, as that can indicate errors on input.

Comment: Quibble, `size_t len; do { fgets(string,SIZE,stdin); len = strlen(string) } while { len > 1 && string[len-1] != '\n'};` to prevent multiple call to `strlen`.